# change form action based on radio button is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a form that allows users to edit the administrators of a post but also create new administrators for the post.

This form has some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a a post. When some radio button (administrator) is clicked the details of the administrator are populated in the form fields. When the "Update" button is clicked the details of the administrator are updated.

This part was working fine.

**Doubt:**

But there is a static radio button, "Create new administrator", that allows to create a new administrator. When this radio button is selected the form fields are reseted so the user can insert values to create a new admin when it clicks on the "Store" button.

I have the jQuery below to change the form action based on radio button selection.

With this js part to change the form action based on the selected radio button the code is not working properly, there are 3 issues:

- When an administrator (radio button) is selected the form fields are not populated with that administrator details (this was working fine before insert the js part to change the form action based on radio button selection)
- Also when the "Create new admin" radio button is selected the form fields are not reseted.
- When the "Store" button is clicked also it appears and error: "Creating default object from empty value".

**form:**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('admins.update', ['id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @foreach($administrators $admin)
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="">
              {{$admin->name}}
            </label>
          </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_administrator"
             value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
          Create new administrator
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name">
  </div>

  <!-- below I have more form fields like administrator name, email, etc -->

  <input type="submit" id="adminStoreButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
  <input type="submit" id="adminUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
  </form>
```

**jQuery: to show the details of the admin based on radio button selection, to hide and show the store/update button and to change the form action based on radio button selection**

```
   var admins = {!!  $administrators !!}

    $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {

    if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
        $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
        $("#adminStoreButton").show();
        form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    }
    else{
        $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
        $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
        form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    }

    let id = $(this).attr("id");

    let data = administrators.find(e => e.id == id) || {
        name: "",
       email: "",
       ...: ""
    };
   $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
    ...
    });
```

**// update admins routes**

```
Route::get('post/edit/{id}/admins',    [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit', 'as'=>'admins.edit']);
Route::post('post/update/{id}/admins', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@update', 'as'=>'admins.update']);
Route::post('post/store/{id}/admins', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@store', 'as'=>'admins.store']);
```

**Administrator controller update method:**

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id){


        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
          ...
        ]);


        $adminToUpdate = Administrator::find($request->radiobutton);

        $adminToUpdate->name = $request->name;
        ...

        $adminToUpdate->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

**Administrator controller edit method:**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $administrators = Administrator::where('post_id', $id)->get();

        return view('administrators.edit')
            ->with('post', $post)
            ->with('administrators', $administrators));
    }
```

**Administrator controller store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $post = Post::find($id);

    Administrator::create([
        'nome' => $request->name,
        'post_id' => $post->id
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: Change your jQuery click function like this `$(document).on('click', input[name^=radiobutton]", function () {}`

Comment: Form has admin.update route on submit for editing administrator's data but where is admin.store route in order to store new administrator's information?

Comment: Thanks I update the routes with the "admins.store" instead of "admins.update", it was a typo. With the $(document).on('click'...) it is also not working properly, I get the same issue.

Comment: After updating jQuery part does hide and show works correctly? What isn't working properly?

Comment: When some radio button is selected dont appears the details of that radio button (administrator). Also when the "Create new admin" is clicked the form fields dont reset and also the button dont change from "Update" to "Store".

Comment: Without this part to change the action of the form "        form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
" based on radio button selection the update works fine, the details of the selected admin appear in the form fields and the update works correct. But with this jquery code to change the action of the form the update also dont works properly.

Comment: It's hard to debug jQuery part. You're messing your logic. One advice is make single route for update and store. Something like this. `Route::post('post/update/admins/{$id?}'` Here $id is optional and if it is null you need to create new administrator or else find and update administrator's record.

Comment: One more thing var admins is an object. Find using loadash provided by laravel. like this. `var admin_data = _.find(admin, function(o) { return o.id < SOME_ID_VALUE; });`

Comment: Thanks, with this jquery it works: if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
    $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
    $("#adminStoreButton").show();
}
else{
    $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
    $("#adminStoreButton").hide();

}. When a radio button that corresponds to an administrator is selected the form fields are populated, when the "Create new admin" is clicked the form fields are reseted.

Comment: But adding to the jquery the change form action part, that part that was working stop working: if($(this).attr("id") == "create_administrator"){
    $("#adminUpdateButton").hide();
    $("#adminStoreButton").show();
    form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
}
else{
    $("#adminUpdateButton").show();
    $("#adminStoreButton").hide();
    form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

}.

Comment: And the route "Route::post('post/update/admins/{$id?}" maybe cant be like that because its also necessary the id of the post because its an update of an administrator of the post, so it should be "Route::post('post/{$id}/update/admins/{$id?}"?

Comment: For updating form attribute change your code like this. 
`var url = "{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}";
form.attr('action', url);` give it a try. URL based on your requirement. Just giving you an idea.

Comment: In the console it appears an error "form is not defined".

Comment: Do one thing. Give id in form tag like this `<form id="admin-form">` and update your code like this. `$("#admin-form").attr('action',url);`

Comment: Thanks it works, can you give an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer is a collaborative effort between me and Jon.

Dividing the problem into different parts.

**1) When you are dealing with multiple checkbox/radio button with same name than you should caret instead of name only.**

***Fix 1:***

```
Replace $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {} with 

$(document).on('click', input[name^=radiobutton]", function () {}
```

**2) Laravel comes with Lodash as preloaded. Use it whenever and wherever possible.**

***Fix 2:***

```
var admins = {!!  $administrators !!}
let id = $(this).attr("id");

let data = administrators.find(e => e.id == id) || {
        name: "",
       email: "",
       ...: ""
};

replace this logic with _.find method of lodash.

var admins = {!!  $administrators !!}
var admin_data = _.find(admin, function(o) { return o.id < SOME_ID_VALUE; });
```

**3) A form doesn't have an ID attribute. Assign ID so it can be used for setting an action attribute of form.**

***Fix 3:***

```
<form id="admin-form">

Change your code
//Remove this entirely
form.attr('action', '{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');

//Replace with following lines of code.
//Route is upto you. Whichever route you want to pass.
var url = "{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}"; form.attr('action', url);
```

**Suggesstions**
When you are dealing with editing and creating within same form try to avoid multiple routes.

Here routes can be handled like this. 
`Route::post('post/update/{id}/admins/{adminID?}', [ 'uses' => 'AdminController@update', 'as'=>'admins.update']);`

$admingID is optional if not pass then null so you should create new administrator record else update existing administrator's record.